# PDF-Express Error: Font symbol is not embedded

Tags: libreoffice, ieee

I am not sure it is the right place to ask such a question, sorry.

I have libre office, and a paper, which is written using a IEEE format.

Now when i try to export to PDF, and try to pass pdf-express it fails with error

```
Font Symbol is not embedded 10x
```

I do not know where is the problem, there is only 1 font: Times New Roman, of course different sizes.

I tried "Export as PDF..." and checked "Embed Fonts", but no chance so far.

A month ago, i tried the same paper with OpenOffice, and i do not remember such error, now i become to a situation that i have to change paper a bit, and try the same paper with LibreOffice i get this error. Is this error about LibreOffice?

Comment: how silly i am, it says font "Symbol", i could not notice Symbol as a font, and could not understand the error, going to look for it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look at this answer, really simple!

[How to repair a PDF file and embed missing fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857849/how-to-repair-a-pdf-file-and-embed-missing-fonts/13131101#13131101)

Also, my comment as follows :)

On win32, if you have installed ghostScript, the command may look like:

```
gswin32c -sFONTPATH=C:\Windows\Fonts -o output-pdf-with-embedded-fonts.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress input-pdf-where-some-fonts-are-not-embedded.pdf
```

(find the exe file on your system, maybe add it to PATH -- the environment variable, if necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Open this PDF file with Adobe acrobat, then choose file->print. Use adobe PDF as the printer to print the file and save it as pdf file. All fonts will be embedded.

Answer (score 1):

I want to post an answer because I had the same issue and none of the standard solutions(i.e. print to PDF or using PDF Express to convert the source files into a PDF) were working out.

When I actually tried to debug the issue, I figured out that the problem was being caused by text in the **figure/image *pdfs*** that I had embedded within the file (as figures). The problem was solved simply by using the image files (i.e. .png or .jpg files) of the respective figures instead.

Answer (score 0):

Generate ps from pdf using pdftops, using Xpdf.

Use Ghostscript to embed fonts:

```
gsWin64 -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true 
    -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile=d:\Output_filename.pdf Input_filename.ps
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I understood the cause of the problem. If you upload the article directly as a Word file .doc format, the problem is fixed. The purpose of IEEE is to convert to PDF in IEEE format. When I add it there as a PDF, it tries to convert it from PDF to PDF and gives an error.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem and I think simply by creating the PDF file using PDF express using your source file is the simplest and easiest solution. If you are using latest then just zip or rar your source file (dvi file, eps etc.) and then just build the pdf file using PDF Express. This will solve your problem. I have found one article [IEEE PDF Express Error Message – Font is not Embedded Solution](http://www.techntechie.com/ieee-pdf-express-error-message-font-is-not-embedded-solution.html) which can help you in this regard.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the absolute solution for font embedding problem:
I just uploaded the .doc file instead of .pdf and it worked well for me.