# How to repair a PDF file and embed missing fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, truetype, pdftk

I use `pdftk` to repair some failures in corrupted PDF files, but I faced another problem which is not fixed by `pdftk` (or at least I do not know how to do so).

I have PDF files with text based on `TrueType` fonts, but the fonts have not been embedded during PDF creation. Now I want to embed the required fonts to the existing files.

Is there a command-line tool (like `pdftk`) to embed missing fonts by providing path to `TTF` files?

Answer (score 34):

You can use *Ghostscript* to embed missing fonts. Run the command like this:

```
gs                                             \
  -o file-with-embedded-fonts.pdf              \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite                            \
  -dEmbedAllFonts=true                         \
  -sFONTPATH="/path/to/ttf;/other/path/to/ttf" \
   input-without-embedded-fonts.pdf
```

See also this answer:

- [**How do I embed fonts in an existing PDF?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231656/359307)

Comment: On win32, if you have installed ghostScript, the command may look like: gswin32c -sFONTPATH=C:\Windows\Fonts -o output-pdf-with-embedded-fonts.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress input-pdf-where-some-fonts-are-not-embedded.pdf (find the exe file on your system, maybe add it to PATH -- the environment variable, if necessary)

Comment: @Qtax: not needed I think -- this is supposed to be the default setting for Ghostscript anyway when embedding fonts.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle you are right! Removing that comment (and this one), and adding one to make people aware that font subsetting is done.

Comment: `gs` does font subsetting by default when embedding fonts (that is only embedding the glyphs of the font that are used in the PDF). Can be disabled with `-dSubsetFonts=false`.

Comment: This breaks PDF files that have forms in them. Does anyone know of the `gs` flag that will preserve the forms?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: FOSS software and PDF forms -- a long chapter in the book "List of important functionality missing or sucking in FOSS"....

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same problem (on Ubuntu 14.04) and I found the following solution:

- install Acrobat Reader
- print "print to file" into a postscript file ("foo.ps") and "advanced -> print as image"
- then on the console use `ps2pdf foo.ps foo.pdf` and the result is a file with embedded fonts and the original content

The intermediate postscript file is much bigger (650KB) than the input file (56KB) but the resulting PDF is moderate in size again (82KB).

I do not know why this works, i.e.,

- why "print as image to file" seems to create an image but also preserves font information,
- why ps2pdf recovers this font information, and
- why there are fonts in the resulting PDF at all because it should only be an image, right?.

But the result is a PDF with all fonts embedded and a size similar to the original file.

Comment: It worked for me by just printing to ps-file, without saving it as an image. [Some people complain](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-to-embed-fonts-at-compile-time-with-pdflatex) that pdf -> ps -> pdf conversion is not the way to go, but you seriously rescued my PhD thesis from doom with this post.

Comment: I like your approach but changed it in my case. I did not want to use Acrobat so I just did it with evince (standard Gnome PDF reader) print to File, chose Post Script (no image option needed) and then ps2pdf the resulting pdf again. That worked and I did not need to search for the paths for the fonts as necessary for the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131101/414075).

Comment: Using ps2pdf directly on the damaged pdf worked for me for fixing fonts: `ps2pdf foo.pdf foo_fixed.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @t-bltg in a comment, Ghostscript now comes with a `ps2pdf` command which will embed missing fonts automatically.

```
ps2pdf -sFONTPATH="." in.pdf out.pdf
```

That should be all you need.

#### Troubleshooting

- The above command presumes the necessary .ttf or .otf file is in the current  working directory (`"."`). If it is not, you can change `.` to directory where the font file lives. For example:

  ```
  ps2pdf -sFONTPATH="~/.local/share/fonts/" input.pdf output.pdf
  ```

  (Note, you must specify a directory, not a font file.)
- Make sure that the fontname the PDF is looking for is the same as the name embedded in the font file. For example, if the PDF wants a font named "Fantasy Bold", but the font file defines a font named "Fantasy" or "Fantasy Bold Neue LT Pro", this method will not work.

#### Bonus: The 14 type families

Even without specifying FONTPATH, Ghostscript knows about the 14 standard Postscript Level 2 fonts, including their old names. For example, modern systems sometimes do not render "New Century Schlbk" correctly because they expect "New Century Schoolbook". A simple `ps2pdf in.pdf out.pdf` solves the problem.