# How can one embed a font into a PDF with free linux command line tools?

Tags: linux, pdf, command-line, fonts

I have a set o f PDFs that display fine on my machine. However, they use non-standard fonts installed on my machine. As they are not embedded (as per [pdffonts](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdffonts1.html)), they don't display on other machines. How can I embed this font using only linux command line tools.

BTW, under Windows, Adobe Acrobat could be used as explained [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5877348_embed-fonts-pdf-files.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be solved by carefully reading these answers:

- [**How to repair a PDF file and embed missing fonts**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131101/359307)
- [**How do I embed fonts in an existing PDF?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234150/359307)

Answer (score 41):

Try this:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Comment: @ingomueller.net: This command will work, if your non-standard fonts are located in a standard path that Ghostscript knows about. Otherwise, look at the other links I provided in my own answer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  My document (created by `pdflatex`) was not accepted by the ScholarOne Manuscripts (S1M) document submission service until I ran it though ghostscript with this command.

Comment: instead of the `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` canon you can also just set `-dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true` (the former to taste)