# What is the best way to replace not embedded fonts in a PDF with others of the same family?

Tags: r, pdf, fonts, latex, embedding

I didn't realize that statistical charts and graphs made by R were using fonts not installed on my Windows machine, these are:
`Helvetica`
`Helvetica-Bold`
`Helvetica-Oblique`
`ZapfDingbats`

I discovered that by running `pdffonts <file.name.pdf>` from command line. So these fonts were not embedded in the PDF files.

I have my dissertation sent for printing but the printing house says these fonts need to be embedded in the PDF file. I have written it using `LaTeX` and included graphs as PDFs.

How to replace or substitute these fonts (some are licensed) with very similar ones without distorting the graphs in the individual PDFs? I don't intend to use commercial utilities.

**Notes**
 - Windows 7 32 bit
 - This post was similar:

https://superuser.com/a/223687/212779

However, it was done with a commercial program and is relatively old by now. There might be better new ideas to overcome this problem. I hope so.

**My trial so far**
I have succeeded to do the replacement using the procedure in the following post by some expert in Ghostscript: https://superuser.com/q/39167/212779

This requires [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) to be installed (I have version 9.15) plus Adobe [PostScript](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=1500) for Windows, a universal one and this script from command line:

```
gswin32c ^
 -dNOPAUSE ^
 -dBATCH ^
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 ^
 -dHaveTrueTypes=true ^
 -dSubsetFonts=true ^
 -sOutputFile="c:\path\to\somename.pdf" ^
 -c ".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams" ^
 -f "c:\path\to\somename.ps"
```

**Question**
How to get the generated `.ps` postscript file and subsequently the `.pdf` file (which is now gracefully embedded with a similar font) having the same size of the original PDF, i.e., cropped exactly to the same dimensions of the original PDF file?

If I leave all default settings in Adobe Reader (version XI) -- not to be confused with the commercial Adobe Professional, I get the same size in `.ps` file, so what I really need is some code in Ghostscript to preserved dimensions of the `.ps` file when generate the final PDF, any help? BTW, I open the `.ps` file with `SumatraPDF` viewer.

Comment: Have you tried the `-dEmbedAllFonts=true` option to gswin32c? It was mentioned in [12857849](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857849/how-to-repair-a-pdf-file-and-embed-missing-fonts). From that example, it imports and exports a PDF directly instead of postscript.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked very well. Feel free to post the code and make it an answer. Is there any way to batch process multiple PDFs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close: a previous SO question ([12857849](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857849/how-to-repair-a-pdf-file-and-embed-missing-fonts)) mentioned adding `-dEmbedAllFonts=true` to the command line of gswin32c.

Your second question (in a comment) for batch-processing multiple PDFs can be done in multiple ways, the "best" being what is easiest for you to understand, maintain, and using a tool to which you have ready access.

In R:

```
fnames <- list.files(pattern = 'doctorate-.*.pdf')
for (fn in fnames) {
    ofn <- paste0(gsub('\\.pdf$', '', fn, ignore.case = TRUE), '-withfonts.pdf')
    message('Processing: ', fn, ' --> ', ofn)
    system2('gswin32c',
            paste0('-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ',
                   '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dHaveTrueTypes=true -dSubsetFonts=true ',
                   '-dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile="', ofn, '" ',
                   '-c ".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams" ',
                   '-f "', fn, '"'))
}
```

This is a bit verbose. If you add `stdout=FALSE` in `system2`, all you should see is something like:

```
Processing: doctorate-1.pdf --> doctorate-1-withfonts.pdf
Processing: doctorate-2.pdf --> doctorate-2-withfonts.pdf
Processing: doctorate-3.pdf --> doctorate-3-withfonts.pdf
```

In `bash`:

```
for fn in doctorate-*.pdf ; do
    ofn="$(basename ${fn} .pdf)-withfonts.pdf"
    echo "Processing: ${fn} --> ${ofn}"
    gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
             -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dHaveTrueTypes=true -dSubsetFonts=true ^
             -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile="${ofn}" ^
             -c ".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams" ^
             -f "${fn}"
done
```

(Note that if you are doing this in a bash terminal under msys2 in windows, this will likely fail since msys2 sees "/prepress" and assumes it is a path, converting it to `c:/msys64/prepress`, which obviously means nothing to gs ...)

Comment: +1, for batch processing, is it required to run R session in the same folder? or is there a way to tell R where the path to folder is?

Comment: Not strictly, though this example assumes both that and the fact that `gswin32c` is in your executable path. If you changed the first line to be `fnames <- list.files(path='/some/path', pattern = 'doctorate-.*.pdf', full.names=TRUE)`, it should still work just fine (haven't tested it). See `help(list.files)` for some other options.

Answer (score 1):

All what is needed in Windows is the following steps:

*Step 1*
Install Ghostscript and add to the PATH variables (`Win + break` is useful shortcut)

*Step 2*
Run this script from command line and go the target folder where you have the bad PDF (I do this to avoid writing the whole path).

*Step 3*

Check your bad PDF by running pdffont from command line:

```
pdffonts input-pdf-where-some-fonts-are-not-embedded.pdf
```

*Step 4*
Run this code to get the desired PDF with embedded fonts:

```
gswin32c ^  
-sFONTPATH=C\Windows\Fonts ^
-o output-pdf-with-embedded-fonts.pdf  ^
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
"input-pdf-where-some-fonts-are-not-embedded.pdf"
```

Comment: Was `-dEmbedAllFonts=true ` not required after all?

Comment: No, it wasn't required nor mentioned in the comment of the same post by `fstang` on win32.